# When PHP is builting URL, script stop working

Tags: php, url

Everytime I run this part of my script, stript stop working.

```
$url = $this->getUrl . '?id=' . $this->apiKey . '&email=' . urlencode($this->email) . '&produkt[]=' . urlencode($this->product) . '&orderid=' . $this->order_id;
foreach ($this->products as $product) {
$url .= '&produkt[]=' . urlencode($product);
}
```

When I change `$url = $this->getUr ... ...` to `$url = http://blablabla.com/blabla... ...` all is working fine.

Where is a bug?

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

```
$url = $this->getUrl . '?id=' . $this->apiKey . '&email=' . urlencode($this->email) . '&produkt[]=' . urlencode($this->product) . '&orderid=' . $this->order_id;
foreach ($this->products as $product) {
$url .= '&produkt[]=' . urlencode($product);
}
```

to

```
$url = $getUrl . '?id=' . $apiKey . '&email=' . urlencode($this->email) . '&produkt[]=' . urlencode($product) . '&orderid=' . $order_id;
```

`$this->` is not defined in my script, so after deleting it, script works fine. But everybody must define `$product` before url is creating. It works in my script!

Answer (score 0):

yeah, set put "php_flag display_errors on" into .htaccess file in that folder and you'll see where is the problem.

Comment: `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /domains1/vx592000/public/www_root/wp-content/themes/sommerce/functions.php` 
My error message :(

Comment: As I red some articles, I can not use `$this`. I changed my function to public and it gives me error `syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC` ... how make my script build the URL?

Comment: $url = $getUrl . '?id=' . $apiKey . '&email=' . urlencode($email) . '&produkt[]=' . urlencode($product) . '&orderid=' . $order_id;
    foreach ($products as $product) {
    $url .= '&produkt[]=' . urlencode($product);
    }

I needed delete `$this` and script works fine. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome!
You can mark answer as helpful if you like =)